# Kinesis put records not returned in response from get records request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I have a Scala app using the `aws-java-sdk-kinesis` to issue a series of putRecord requests to a local kinesis stream.

The response returned after each putRecord request indicates its successfully putting the records into the stream.

The scala code making the putRecordRquest:

```
 def putRecord(kinesisClient: AmazonKinesis, value: Array[Byte], streamName: String): Try[PutRecordResult] = Try {
    val putRecordRequest = new PutRecordRequest()
    putRecordRequest.setStreamName(streamName)
    putRecordRequest.setData(ByteBuffer.wrap(value))
    putRecordRequest.setPartitionKey("integrationKey")

    kinesisClient.putRecord(putRecordRequest)
  }
```

To confirm this I have a small python app that basically consumes from the stream (initialStreamPosition: `LATEST`). And prints the records it finds by iterating through the shard-iterators. But unexpectedly however it returns an empty set of records for each obtained shardIterator.

Trying this using the aws cli tool, I do however get records returned for the same shardIterator. I am confused? How can that be?

Running the python consumer (with `LATEST`), returns:

```
Shard-iterators: ['AAAAAAAAAAH9AUYVAkOcqkYNhtibrC9l68FcAQKbWfBMyNGko1ypHvXlPEuQe97Ixb67xu4CKzTFFGoLVoo8KMy+Zpd+gpr9Mn4wS+PoX0VxTItLZXxalmEfufOqnFbz2PV5h+Wg5V41tST0c4X0LYRpoPmEnnKwwtqwnD0/VW3h0/zxs7Jq+YJmDvh7XYLf91H/FscDzFGiFk6aNAVjyp+FNB3WHY0d']

Records: []
```

If doing the "same" with the aws cli tool however I get:

```
> aws kinesis get-records --shard-iterator AAAAAAAAAAH9AUYVAkOcqkYNhtibrC9l68FcAQKbWfBMyNGko1ypHvXlPEuQe97Ixb67xu4CKzTFFGoLVoo8KMy+Zpd+gpr9Mn4wS+PoX0VxTItLZXxalmEfufOqnFbz2PV5h+Wg5V41tST0c4X0LYRpoPmEnnKwwtqwnD0/VW3h0/zxs7Jq+YJmDvh7XYLf91H/FscDzFGiFk6aNAVjyp+FNB3WHY0d --endpoint-url http://localhost:4567
```

Returns:

```
{"Records":[{"SequenceNumber":"49625122979782922897342908653629584879579547704307482626","ApproximateArrivalTimestamp":1640263797.328,"Data":{"type":"Buffer","data":[123,34,116,105,109,101,115,116,97,109,112,34,58,49,54,52,48,50,54,51,55,57,55,44,34,100,116,109,34,58,49,54,52,48,50,54,51,55,57,55,44,34,101,34,58,34,101,34,44,34,116,114,97,99,107,101,114,95,118,101,114,115,105,111,110,34,58,34,118,101,114,115,105,111,110,34,44,34,117,114,108,34,58,34,104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47,116,101,115,116,46,99,111,109,34,44,34,104,99,99,34,58,102,97,108,115,101,44,34,115,99,34,58,49,44,34,99,111,110,116,101,120,116,34,58,123,34,101,116,34,58,34,101,116,34,44,34,100,101,118,34,58,34,100,101,118,34,44,34,100,119,101,108,108,34,58,49,44,34,111,105,100,34,58,49,44,34,119,105,100,34,58,49,44,34,115,116,97,116,101,34,58,123,34,108,99,34,58,123,34,99,111,100,101,34,58,34,115,111,109,101,45,99,111,100,101,34,44,34,105,100,34,58,34,115,111,109,101,45,105,100,34,125,125,125,44,34,121,117,105,100,34,58,34,102,53,101,52,57,53,98,102,45,100,98,102,100,45,52,102,53,102,45,56,99,56,98,45,53,97,56,98,50,56,57,98,52,48,49,97,34,125]},"PartitionKey":"integrationKey"},{"SequenceNumber":"49625122979782922897342908653630793805399163707871723522","ApproximateArrivalTimestamp":1640263817.338,"Data":{"type":"Buffer","data":[123,34,116,105,109,101,115,116,97,109,112,34,58,49,54,52,48,50,54,51,56,49,55,44,34,100,116,109,34,58,49,54,52,48,50,54,51,56,49,55,44,34,101,34,58,34,101,34,44,34,116,114,97,99,107,101,114,95,118,101,114,115,105,111,110,34,58,34,118,101,114,115,105,111,110,34,44,34,117,114,108,34,58,34,104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47,116,101,115,116,46,99,111,109,34,44,34,104,99,99,34,58,102,97,108,115,101,44,34,115,99,34,58,49,44,34,99,111,110,116,101,120,116,34,58,123,34,101,116,34,58,34,101,116,34,44,34,100,101,118,34,58,34,100,101,118,34,44,34,100,119,101,108,108,34,58,49,44,34,111,105,100,34,58,49,44,34,119,105,100,34,58,49,44,34,115,116,97,116,101,34,58,123,34,108,99,34,58,123,34,99,111,100,101,34,58,34,115,111,109,101,45,99,111,100,101,34,44,34,105,100,34,58,34,115,111,109,101,45,105,100,34,125,125,125,44,34,121,117,105,100,34,58,34,102,53,101,52,57,53,98,102,45,100,98,102,100,45,52,102,53,102,45,56,99,56,98,45,53,97,56,98,50,56,57,98,52,48,49,97,34,125]},"PartitionKey":"integrationKey"},{"SequenceNumber":"49625122979782922897342908653632002731218779711435964418","ApproximateArrivalTimestamp":1640263837.347,"Data":{"type":"Buffer","data":[123,34,116,105,109,101,115,116,97,109,112,34,58,49,54,52,48,50,54,51,56,51,55,44,34,100,116,109,34,58,49,54,52,48,50,54,51,56,51,55,44,34,101,34,58,34,101,34,44,34,116,114,97,99,107,101,114,95,118,101,114,115,105,111,110,34,58,34,118,101,114,115,105,111,110,34,44,34,117,114,108,34,58,34,104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47,116,101,115,116,46,99,111,109,34,44,34,104,99,99,34,58,102,97,108,115,101,44,34,115,99,34,58,49,44,34,99,111,110,116,101,120,116,34,58,123,34,101,116,34,58,34,101,116,34,44,34,100,101,118,34,58,34,100,101,118,34,44,34,100,119,101,108,108,34,58,49,44,34,111,105,100,34,58,49,44,34,119,105,100,34,58,49,44,34,115,116,97,116,101,34,58,123,34,108,99,34,58,123,34,99,111,100,101,34,58,34,115,111,109,101,45,99,111,100,101,34,44,34,105,100,34,58,34,115,111,109,101,45,1pre05,100,34,125,125,125,44,34,121,117,105,100,34,58,34,102,53,101,52,57,53,98,102,45,100,98,102,100,45,52,102,53,102,45,56,99,56,98,45,53,97,56,98,50,56,57,98,52,48,49,97,34,125]},"PartitionKey":"integrationKey"}],"NextShardIterator":"AAAAAAAAAAE+9W/bI4CsDfzvJGN3elplafFFBw81/cVB0RjojS39hpSglW0ptfsxrO6dCWKEJWu1f9BxY7OZJS9uUYyLn+dvozRNzKGofpHxmGD+/1WT0MVYMv8tkp8sdLdDNuVaq9iF6aBKma+e+iD079WfXzW92j9OF4DqIOCWFIBWG2sl8wn98figG4x74p4JuZ6Q5AgkE41GT2Ii2J6SkqBI1wzM","MillisBehindLatest":0}
```

The actual python consumer I have used in many other settings to introspec other kinesis streams we have and its working as expected. But for some reason here its not working.

Does anyone have a clue what might be going on here?

Comment: If the CLI returns records but your consumer doesn't, that indicates a bug in your consumer -- even if you've used it successfully elsewhere. Unfortunately, you don't show your consumer code, so nobody will be able to help you find that bug.

Comment: fair point @Parsifal, in this case I was able though to identify issue. Since I am using Kinesalite, which doesn't support CBOR, I had to disable it after that I got it working. Will provide an answer if anyone else faces the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was finally able to identify the issue, and perhaps it will be useful for someone else with similar problem.

In my setup, I am using a local kinesis stream (kinesalite) which doesn't support [CBOR](https://cbor.io/). You have to disable this explicitly otherwise I was seeing the following error when trying to deserialize the received record.

```
Unable to unmarshall response (We expected a VALUE token but got: START_OBJECT). Response Code: 200, Response Text: OK
```

In my case, setting the environment variable: `AWS_CBOR_DISABLE=1` did the trick